# Cordova-SQLitePlugin in PhoneGap: Uncaught TypeError cannot call method 'opendatabase' of undefined

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, typeerror

I'm trying to use a pre-popuated database, but I keep getting this error:

```
11-10 22:53:35.781: D/CordovaLog(20142): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'openDatabase' of undefined
11-10 22:53:35.781: D/CordovaLog(20142): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 8 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'openDatabase' of undefined
11-10 22:53:35.781: E/Web Console(20142): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'openDatabase' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:8
```

Here is the code:
HTML

```html
<html>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <div class="app">
            <h1>AAAA</h1>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("test.db", "1.0", "testsstst", 20000);
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Seems you didn't install the plugin correctly.

Comment: Hi Omar even I have the same issue now. How did you solve this issue?

Comment: please answer my question on the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737426/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-opendatabase-of-undefined-sqlite-plugin

Comment: Im sorry but it was a long time ago and I dont remember how/if I solved it.

Comment: my bad. That's fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should also include 'SQLitePlugin.js' in your HTML like this:

```
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
...
</body>
```