# Uncaught TypeError cannot call method 'opendatabase' of undefined-SQLite plugin with cordova 3.5

Tags: android, jquery, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

I don't know why does this happen. I am using Sqlite plugin in my application. It is working fine. I am able to store and retrieve data from DB. But the problem is When I am trying to retrieve data on home page(i.e, application start page) I'm getting the following error,

[image]

But If I use same code in second page of my application, It is working fine. So How can I populate DB values application start page.

Code,

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
         redirectHomePage();
    }); 

function redirectHomePage()
{
    alert("go to home page");
     var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "test.db"});
     db.transaction(function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql("select distinct Category from Locationlog;", [], function (tx, res) {
     $("#select-choice").empty();
     var optionheading = '<option value="Select Category">Select Category</option>';
     $("#select-choice").append(optionheading);
     alert("length: "+ res.rows.length);
     for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++)
        {
           var opt  = '<option value="';
           opt += res.rows.item(i).Category;
           opt += '">';
           opt += res.rows.item(i).Category;
           opt += '</option>';
           $("#select-choice").append(opt).selectmenu('refresh');
           $("#locationList").empty();
        }

   });
  });
  $.mobile.changePage('#homePage', "slide", false, true);
}
```

My application home page id is "homepage". I'm working on android platform with cordova-3.5. Any suggestions how to populate DB before loading first page. I tried "pageshow" I got the same error. Any other methods?

[image]

Comment: try to set the **db** variable global, that is outside the redirecthomepage() call. Also ready() should be fired after the deviceready event is fired.

Comment: you need to wait for deviceready event to fired before using the sqlite plugin as shown in the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement in your code will fail if you have not included the **sqlite Plugin** in your project.

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "test.db"});
```

Also you should be waiting for the deviceready event to get fired before using cordova plugins.
You can use **window.openDatabase()** call which creates sqlite DB and does not need the sqlite plugin.
Below is the code for using the openDatabase call in you app.

if your sqlite plugin is working correctly then change the db call to.

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "test.db"});
```

code that does not use the sqlite plugin.

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    // Populate the database
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }
```

The above code snippet is taken from the Cordova API doc. See [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) for details. Even though the documentation is for 3.0 it should work for 3.5

Comment: Yes I have initialize the db value in "OnDeviceReady" method and I wrote the document.ready method after "OnDeviceReady" method. Still I am getting the same error. I have attached my error log in my question. please check the same.

Comment: @Precious Writing the document.ready after the "OnDeviceReady" won't help. These are **Async** calls. They do not happen in a sequence the code is written. You need to write the document.ready **INSIDE** the **OnDeviceReady** call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm aware of this Async calls. you solved my problem. It is working fine now